# JSF 1.2 - Export to Excel and rename file

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

In a legacy code, the excel export is done by rendering a xhtml (jsf) page and by changing the contentType to "`application/vnd.ms-excel`" the file is automatically downloaded by the browser and this file can be opened with excel without any problem.

What I would like to change is the extension of the file. When the file is downloaded, it has the 'xhtml' extension. I would like to use a proper excel extension ('xls').

The file downloaded is called `summaryTransactionReports.xhtml`. I would like to be `summaryTransactionReports.xls`.

How can I achieve this with the minimum impact?

Here goes the code:

**summaryTransactionReports.xhtml**

```
<h:commandButton action="#{TransactionReports.createTransactionSummaryReportAction}"
                     value="#{msg.transactionReports_createReport}"
                     styleClass="form-button text-form-button"/>
```

**TransactionReportsMBean.java**

```
public String createTransactionSummaryReportAction()
{
    [...]
    Lots of thing here!!!
    [...]

    //Page we go to depends on the report type requested
    String nextPage;
    switch (reportType)
    {
        case REPORT_TYPE_HTML:
            nextPage = OutcomeConstants.VIEW_TRANSACTION_SUMMARY_REPORT;
            break;

        case REPORT_TYPE_EXCEL:
            nextPage = "viewExcelSummaryTransactionReport";
            break;

        case REPORT_TYPE_PRINTER_FRIENDLY:
            nextPage = OutcomeConstants.VIEW_TRANSACTION_SUMMARY_REPORT_PRINTER_FRIENDLY;
            break;

        default:
            nextPage = OutcomeConstants.VIEW_TRANSACTION_SUMMARY_REPORT;
            break;
    }

    return nextPage;
}
```

**viewExcelSummaryTransactionReports.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ac="http://aconitesolutions.com/jsf-custom">
    <body>

        <ui:composition template="excelMainPage.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="title">#{msg.transactionReportsSummary_Title}</ui:define>

            <ui:define name="productName">Transaction Enabler</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content"><ui:include src="summaryTransactionReportsContent.xhtml" /></ui:define>
            <ui:define name="header">This is the header stuff</ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

**excelMainPage.xhtml**

```
<f:view contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <head>
        <title>
            <ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <f:loadBundle basename="TRxEMessageResource" var="msg"/>

    <!-- div for displaying tooltips ; manipulated by javascript  -->
    <div id="tooltip" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden"></div>


    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="header">
                    <h2>#{msg.productName}</h2>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 100%;
                border-style: solid;
                border-bottom-width: 2px;
                border-left-width: 0px;
                border-right-width: 0px;
                border-top-width: 0px;
                border-color: #A9A9A9;
                margin-bottom: 5%">
                <div id="titleText">
                    <h2>
                        <ui:insert name="title"/>
                    </h2>

                    <ui:insert name="content">
                        <div>Content goes here</div>
                    </ui:insert>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>

</f:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is recognizable as MSIE specific behavior. That browser indeed doesn't use the filename from `Content-Disposition` header as *Save As* filename. Instead, it uses the filename as it appears in the last path from the request URI, which is in this case the URL of the submitted `<form action>`.

Your best bet is to let JSF send a redirect to a servlet which in turn returns the report. Then you can specify the filename straight in the URL the way MSIE expects.

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/reports/filename.xls");
```

The servlet can look like this:

```
@WebServlet("/reports/*")
public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        // ...
    }

}
```

Additional parameters necessary for generating the report can be passed as request parameters in redirect URL and/or via the session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as usual very quick! I'm working on something else at the moment, so I cannot try what you proposed. I'll come back to you hopefully in few days. Thks again for your time.